# TemplateDoesNotExist error, but template does in fact exist

Tags: django, ubuntu, django-haystack

*Vital stats:*
Ubuntu 11.04
Django 1.3.1

I'm running Haystack backed by Whoosh. The rest of the site functions fine, but when I attempt to search, I get a `TemplateDoesNotExist` exception for a template included in `templates/search/search.html`. The template loader is obviously able to read search.html, or it wouldn't know to try to fetch the include. The included file, `_resultPage.html` is in the same directory, has the same permissions and same owner and group as `search.html`. And, it's not just this one include. If I comment it out, it simply errors out on the next included file.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Any included template in `search.html`. It loads `search.html` but fails on anything included in it. That much was in my question, though, so you have me second-guessing myself.

Comment: "What template?" as in "Where is the template in question, uh, in your question?".

Comment: Is there perhaps some code in _resultPage.html that's throwing an exception not exposed by search.html? I've had instances where an include had an exception, but it wasn't exposed by the page that registered the include.

Comment: How about just load that include template directly with a dummy view. See if it can be loaded?

Comment: Make sure the '_' part is not filtered. I don't know if it's possible...but sometimes I get crazy errors like that.

Comment: Well, the thing is this has been working fine for over a year and a half. I moved the site to a new server and switched it from Cherokee+uwsgi to nginx+gunicorn. Other than that, all code related to this piece of the site in particular is unchanged. It works fine in my dev environment, including running a dev nginx+gunicorn setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was under a time crunch, so I simply rolled all the included templates right into search.html and called it a day.

Answer (score 2):

The `include` tag relies on `django.template.loader.get_template` which searches templates in normal way instead of by relative path. Do you use `"_resultPage.html"` or `"search/_resultPage.html"`. If you use the first form, the absolute path of `'template/search/search'` must be in `TEMPLATE_DIRS`. You could check by doing the following:

```
>>> from django.template.loader import get_template
>>> get_template('_resultPage.html')
```

Comment: I'm using `{% include 'search/_resultPage.html' %}`.

Comment: @ChrisPratt That's weird. Have you figured it out?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I was under a time crunch, so I simply rolled all the included templates right into search.html.